# Magento2, How to save cart in product page

Tags: magento2

[image]

Here I add a form above add to cart button as add to quote on product detail page.

Now I have to save the form in my custom database as **Add to Cart** process.

Can anyone please explain how to **Add to Cart** saving process was work?

I need to replace that **Add to Cart** process for my custom **Add to Quote** button.

Comment: Why don't you just change text from "Add to Cart" to "Add to Quote"?

Comment: No i need to do full process like add to cart..

Comment: For my purpose and also in cart page i have to edit price of and product....Can you give me any suggestion pleasew